# Concat multiple xml elements with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I am trying to write a bash script to extract the multiple "directors" from an xml file [such as this](http://mymovieapi.com/?id=tt1371111&type=xml) and concat them separated by a pipe, i.e. Tom Tykwer|Andy Wachowski.

The relevant xml section is:

```
<directors>
<item>Tom Tykwer</item>
<item>Andy Wachowski</item>
</directors>
```

With xmlstarlet in a bash script the following commands:

```
DIRECTORS=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "imdbdocument/directors/item" mymoviexml)
echo $DIRECTORS
```

give me

```
Tom Tykwer Andy Wachowski
```

and this command directly at the terminal

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "imdbdocument/directors/item" mymovieapi.xml
```

gives me:

```
(empty line)
Tom Tykwer
Andy Wachowski
```

I don't know why the new lines are being added when I am not specifying the -n option.

A few of my searches have suggested something like this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "imdbdocument/directors" -v "item" -o "|" mymovieapi.xml
```

but this just gives me:

```
Tom Tykwer
Andy Wachowski|
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get. I'm seeing this behaviour with xmlstarlet 1.3.1 on Debian Wheezy and xmlstarlet 1.5.0 on Xubuntu 13.10.

Comment: You should use `--text` (or `-T`) since you don't want XML output.

Comment: I have tried the --text option but it hasn't made any difference to the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using only xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v '/imdbdocument/directors/item[1]' -m '/imdbdocument/directors/item[position()>1]' -o '|' -v . mymovieapi.xml
```

I tested with version 1.5, but I believe it should work with earlier versions too.

---

Alternative, using `--if` instead of 2 XPath expressions:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m '/imdbdocument/directors/item' --if 'position() > 1' -o '|' -b -v . mymovieapi.xml
```

`-b` is `--break`, it ends the current statement (conditional or loop), like `}` in C.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's what I was looking for. I see now that my problem was not understanding the -m match and -v "." syntax. I assume that you have split the items into [1] and [position()>1] so that the pipe is only printed between the items, and not at the beginning or end of the output.

Comment: Getting pipes only between items can also be done with `--if`, like in the awk solution. I did it the first way because I tend to think in sets when I'm writing XPath.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "imdbdocument/directors/item" mymovieapi.xml |  awk '1' ORS='|'
```

with output

```
|Tom Tykwer|Andy Wachowski|
```

or if you do not want the leading and trailing pipes `|`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "imdbdocument/directors/item" mymovieapi.xml | awk 'NF>0 {if (i++) printf "|"; printf "%s", $0 } END { printf "\n" }'
```

gives

```
Tom Tykwer|Andy Wachowski
```

Comment: Thank you, I confirm that this works for my purposes and will let me continue. Much appreciated. I would be interested if there is a solution using only xmlstarlet. My reading has indicated this is possible, but my versions of xmlstarlet don't seem to behave in the same way.